# Getting Image And Alt Text of a livelink channel using LAPI_NETp?

Tags: livelink

I am new to LAPI so I am having difficulty in getting the image and alt text that I assigned to my created channel.

I am able to get other general information of LLValue channel object ... But I would also like to get the image of the channel...

I am using this code to get general information of my channel object. But I ExtendedData is undefined and also no image type could be found.

```
   _documents.GetObjectInfo(VolumeID, NodeID, objInfo);
```

How do I get the image ?

Answer (score 0):

LAPI is deprecated. Use JSON or SOAP.